# Xorg occupying too much memory

Tags: linux-mint, xorg, nvidia, desktop-environment

Linux Mint 18.2 here.
I have an nvidia card which I use mainly to run neural networks.
Unfortunately, xorg and related apps do occupy too much memory. For example:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.90                 Driver Version: 384.90                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 750 Ti  Off  | 00000000:02:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 25%   45C    P0     3W /  38W |    666MiB /  4040MiB |      7%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0       557      G   ...-token=1B978818DE5EFEB6C74EFEE5A0DD483D    57MiB |
|    0      1320      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           408MiB |
|    0      1972      G   cinnamon                                      84MiB |
|    0      3042      G   ...-token=E24D57E0D09EDA9EAC9066B1326A0429   111MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

(the two "tokens" are web browsers)

I'd like xorg and other stuff to use just, say, 256 Mb of memory, leaving the rest for CUDA. Is it doable? After all, integrated video cards don't use more than 256 Mb and still everything is displayed just fine.